# newline before enumitem environment

Tags: spacing, enumitem

I want to create an environment that displays "Solution" as a title. After this title I want the text to start after a new line, so the following code should work

```
\newenvironment{sol}{$\triangleright$ \textbf{Solution.} \newline}{$\triangleleft$}
```

It does work, but if I start the text with an enumitem environment, the vertical space of the environment and the `newline` add in a bad way.

Comment: Please make this into a MWE that shows what you're trying to do and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting a `\newline`, use `\par`. With that you also need a `\nobreak` to ensure the subsequent content stays with the "heading." However, if you're using a list, breaking may still occur, so you may require some manual intervention around the page boundary (or resort to packages like [`needspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/needspace) to check the available space on the page).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{sol}{%
  $\triangleright$ \textbf{Solution.} \par\nobreak
}{%
  $\triangleleft$%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{sol}
  \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{sol}

\begin{sol}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[3][1-5]
  \end{itemize}
  \lipsum[3][6-10]
\end{sol}

\begin{sol}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item \lipsum[4][1-5]
  \end{itemize}
  \lipsum[4][6-10]
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```